# Grow edge boundaries using opencv /c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I do not need any code...just let me know if there is any simple way to grow edge boundaries after applying Canny edge detector.

I blurred the image, then I applied Canny edge detector to edetct the edges, now I want to grow the edge boundaries (for example 2 pixel) in each side. Is there any easy way to do that?

```
GaussianBlur(dis, GaussianBlur_After, Size(3, 3), 2, 2 );

Canny( GaussianBlur_After, Canny_After, 100 , 100 * 3, 3 ); 

Canny_After = Scalar::all(0);       //Mask

GaussianBlur_After.copyTo( Canny_After, Detected_Canny);
imshow( "Canny" , Detected_Canny );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes (or maybe, depending on why you want to do it) - morphological dilation (or erode on the background if your image intensities are inverted).

[OpenCV Documentation is here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am working on motion bluring. I want to apply a kind of filtering just into the boundary areas. I thought that maybe a good way could be enhancing the edges. I am not sure that I am in the right way or not!

Comment: @user3091192 if you are trying to remove motion blur you might like to investigate the Wiener filter - [there is a useful OpenCV example here](http://gigadom.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/dabbling-with-wiener-filter-using-opencv/)

Comment: May I ask you to give me your Email address? I am working with depth images..maybe I can share my results with you if you are interested in this area..